# Import And Export data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, import, export

I want to export bulk of records from a table in Sqlserver database to a file and after that i want to import that file to another table in another database .
my project is Asp.net 
my Database is Sqlserver 2008

how do i can do this and what kind of file is faster to use?(XML,TXT,...)

thanks so much

Comment: I want to export bulk of records from a table" - what have you tried?

Comment: why do want to export to a file and then import to table, why don't you just export to the table directly?

Comment: because the table I want to query has belong to another person that let me  access his data base. so I want to save that information in a separation file to do some other operation.but if you know better solution ,please tell me.In addition I want to make this as a facility in my website for manager.because we need to define a new database to retrive its  table of User always.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bcp utility that comes along with sqlserver. More details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx

Answer (score 1):

in sql server management

Right click on DB then select task->generate script

follow wizard....